# Angularjs - Displaying data using $http get from remote server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, jhipster

i want to send a http get request which is not a problem.
But the problem is i want to disply the data from the server page. Does it has to be a JSON page to display the data from remote server ? or any sort of data can be displayed ? if yes , then how
Thank you

```
<div class="form" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Enter URL : <input type="text" ng-model="url" /></p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="CHECK" ng-click="callAPI()" /> </p> <!-- 1 -->
  <p>
    <ul ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <li>{{post}}</li>

</ul>
  </p>

  <div ng-bind="result"></div>  <!--  5 -->
</div>


    <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

                        $scope.callAPI = function() {             // 2
                        //console.log($scope.url);                //3
                            $http.get($scope.url)
                            .success(function(response) {
                             $scope.posts = response.data;       //4
                                });
                             };

                        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

another version of code

```
<div class="form" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Enter URL : <input type="text" ng-model="url" /></p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="CHECK" ng-click="callAPI()" /> </p> 


 <div ng-bind="result"></div>  <!--  5 -->
</div>


        <script>
                var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
                                $scope.$watch('url', function() {
                                  fetch();
                                });



                                function fetch() {

                                    console.log($scope.url);                  
                                        $http.get($scope.url)
                                            .success(function(response) {
                                         $scope.result = response.data;      
                                            });
                                         }

                                   $scope.callAPI= function() {
                                      this.setSelectionRange(0,      this.value.length);
                                }

                          });

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please include your code in your question.

Comment: the question has been updated

Comment: A JSON page ? what do you mean ?

Comment: `.json` files  ... it is possible to display any json data .. but is it possible to display data with diffrent formate , i really dont have a information regarding that

Comment: I believe `$http` will look at the response headers.  If it's not `json` then it won't attempt to parse it.  I haven't verified this yet.  I think that you'll have to deal with HTML encoding when you try to display your posts on the page.

Comment: Using a get request, you can retrieve any type of data you want, you can also load a totally new HTML in your current page. So yes, you can. However, you'll need to parse him or use him in another way, like loading HTML in a balise

Comment: my code is not working @Aks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey i have found my answer of my question ... 
there was a mistake in the source code
here is the right one

```
<div class="form" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as controller">
      <p>Enter URL : <input type="text" ng-model="url" /></p>

      <p><input type="submit" value="CHECK" ng-click="clickButton()" /> </p>                
      <p>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="data in result">
                {{data}}
            </li>

        </ul>
      </p>

    </div>
```

and

```
<script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
                    $scope.clickButton = function() {                               
                        console.log($scope.url);                                
                        $http.get($scope.url)
                            .then(function(response) {
                             $scope.result = response.data;     
                                });
                             };

                        });

    </script>
```

:)

if anyone has a similer problem , i hope this answer will help .. 
cheers

Comment: Thanks bro for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments says, I believe that angular look at the content Type of the response to parse the data. Have you try added the accept header type?

What is the content type of the response?

```
var req = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Accept': change this to whatever content you want to accept
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function functionName(){
            $http.get(URL).success(function(response){

                $scope.variable = response;
            })
        }
```

inside get() put your url, if your url returning any data then it will go to success() function.

Comment: have you inject $http

Comment: yes     i did ,i can recive data if i have a ´.json´ file in the local.

Comment: are you using restfull service ?

Comment: but i want to take the data from remote server

Comment: yeah , it should . may be i have done something wrong. need to rewrite it again .

Comment: Yup, if u get other solution, then let me know

Comment: check my answer @Sam